# Size of y axis in faceted px.line graph not working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to modify the size of my y axis labels for each facet subgraph

```
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, title_font=dict(size=17), row=5, title='abc', title_standoff=0)
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, title_font=dict(size=7), row=6, title='abc', title_standoff=0)
```

But the size doesn't seem to change :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have generated sample data to create a faceted line figure
- key point is that each facet will have it's own yaxis
- used `update_layout()` to unify modification as per your code example.  Every thing is constant except font size.

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {"x": np.linspace(0, 99, 100), "y": np.random.uniform(1, 3, 100)}
        ).assign(facet=f)
        for f in range(2)
    ]
)

px.line(df, x="x", y="y", facet_row="facet").update_layout(
    {
        ax: {"matches": None, "title": {"text": "abc", "font": {"size": s}, "standoff":0}}
        for ax, s in zip(["yaxis", "yaxis2"], [17, 7])
    }
)
```

[image]